Is it possible to get the total CPU usage since last Windows restart?
I would like to get the total CPU usage (for all processes in seconds since last Windows restart) with a command line tool, PS Script or application so that I can calculated the average total usage between two time-stamps.
The Windows Performance counter "\Processor_Information(_Total)% Processor Time" returns the current total usage. It is not convenient because I want to get the usage automatically as good as possible between start and stop of a script.
The Windows SDK function QueryProcessCycleTime returns the usage for a single process. I want the get a similar value for all processes.
The Windows SDK function QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime may be used to calculate the total CPU usage but I am afraid that values may be very inaccurate due to power management (variable CPU frequency, ...)
